# Show full path hierarchy for the current sub-site

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, sub-site, breadcrumb

I have created a modern SharePoint Online intranet for my company. It is required for me to add the full path hierarchy of the current sub-site a user is visiting.

For example, when I visit the IT sub-site it should show the path in the header like:

```
Home > Department > IT
```

This path will help to navigate between sub-sites easily and tell the user the path he took to reach this sub-site.

Comment: so what is your final goal? Where do you want to display the full hierarchy?

Comment: I want to be within the title page of the subsite

Comment: You mean you want the subsite title to display as the full hierarchy?

Comment: yes that what I need

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, breadcrumb(Make the subsite title display as the full hierarchy) is not available for SharePoint Online modern sites. I will suggest you to post in [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration) for Development team.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this SPFX Solution to add breadcrumbs to your site:[Breadcrumb application customizer](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-breadcrumb)